# Node.js - Detecting Image Optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, optimization, jpeg

I am building an application which allows users to upload images to a post.

My issue is that some of these images are 10MB plus. I am currently optimising these using a Node.js module which lowers the file size. It does this by re-creating the image with a quality score of 70.

The issue I have is that some users optimize images before uploading. If an image has already been optimized I don't want to lower the quality any further.

Is there anyway I can detect the quality of an image before it is processed?

Comment: simple idea: u got the width and height, the file size and the file type. so u can calculate the resolution and define your threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use multer, you can see that in size field, if you have only buffer you can use .length method, example:

```
buffer.length() // return 255bytes or 255000 255Kb
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution? How does determining the length of the file buffer have anything to do with determining if an image has already been compressed or not?

Answer (score 0):

with imagemagick you can first identify the size and then convert it into small size or crop it